# How to scan a folder containing an EMF resource for sibling resources

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have developed a DSL with xText and recently add somme enhanced completion.
In a xText-generated editor when calling completion by Ctrl-Space, the completion handler has to perform a folder scanning to look for symbols in another text file of the same DSL.
The entry point is :

```
public class TypesProposalProvider extends AbstractTypesProposalProvider
{
   public void completeQualifiedName_Path(
      EObject                     model,
      Assignment                  assignment,
      ContentAssistContext        context,
      ICompletionProposalAcceptor acceptor )
   {
      super.completeQualifiedName_Path( model, assignment, context, acceptor );
```

I use:

```
      Model root = (Model) context.getRootModel();
      Resource rootRc = root.eResource();
```

to obtain the emf.ecore container of the model.

**And now, how can I look for sibling resources, the other files in the same folder, in term of ecore resource?**

With the another resources, I'll call Resource.load() to populate the underlaying emf.ecore model of the siblings.

*I hope you understand my approximative English (I'm French)...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final version, compact as usual ;-) :

```
Resource   rootRc = root.eResource();
String     rcPath = rootRc.getURI().toPlatformString( true );
IFile      file   = (IFile)ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().findMember( rcPath );
IContainer parent = file.getParent();
for( IResource member : parent.members())
{
   String ext = member.getFileExtension();
   if( ext != null && ext.equals( "types" ))
   {
      String prefix     = member.getName();
      String path       = member.getLocation().toString();
      URI    uriSibling = URI.createFileURI( path );
      prefix = prefix.substring( 0, prefix.length() - ".types".length());
      if( ! rcPath.endsWith( '/' + prefix + ".types" )
         && ( context.getPrefix().isEmpty() || prefix.startsWith( cntxtPrefix )))
      {
         Resource types  = rs.createResource( uriSibling );
         types.load( null );
         for( EObject rc : types.getContents())
         {
            ...
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the sibling models dont refer each other. In that case you can use WorkspaceSynchronizer to get the file from the resource.

Example

```
Resource rootRc = root.eResource();
IFile file = WorkspaceSynchronizer.getFile(rootRc);

IResource parent = file.getParent();

Iresource[] childern = parent.members();

for(<iterate over children>)
     load the children resources.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 'WorkspaceSynchronizer' is not recognized in my version of Eclipse Juno/JDT.

Comment: You need to add the "org.eclipse.emf.workspace" plugin to your dependencies.